# e.pageX with position absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using [this custom JavaScript range slider](https://github.com/tovic/simple-custom-range-slider). I set the wrapper (`.range-slider`) to the following:

```
position:absolute;
left: 60px;
```

Then, when I drag the `dragger`, it isn't in the same position as the cursor. `dragger's` position gets a bit off.

How can I get `dragger` to follow the cursor regardless of where it's parent is at?

I think the relevant code is in the `updateDragger() function`:

```
e = e || window.event;
var pos = !isVertical ? e.pageX : e.pageY;
if (!pos) {
    pos = !isVertical ? e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft : e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
if (down && pos >= rangeOffset && pos <= (rangeOffset + rangeWidth)) {
    dragger.style[!isVertical ? 'left' : 'top'] = (pos - rangeOffset - (draggerWidth / 2)) + 'px';
    cachePosition = Math.round(((pos - rangeOffset) / rangeWidth) * 100);
    config.drag(cachePosition);
}
```

#### JSFiddle

```js
function rangeSlider(elem, config) {

  var html = document.documentElement,
    range = document.createElement('div'),
    dragger = document.createElement('span'),
    down = false,
    rangeWidth, rangeOffset, draggerWidth, cachePosition;

  var defaults = {
    value: 0, // set default value on initiation from `0` to `100` (percentage based)
    vertical: false, // vertical or horizontal?
    rangeClass: "", // add extra custom class for the range slider track
    draggerClass: "", // add extra custom class for the range slider dragger
    drag: function(v) { /* console.log(v); */ } // function to return the range slider value into something
  };

  for (var i in defaults) {
    if (typeof config[i] == "undefined") config[i] = defaults[i];
  }

  function addEventTo(el, ev, fn) {
    if (el.addEventListener) {
      el.addEventListener(ev, fn, false);
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {
      el.attachEvent('on' + ev, fn);
    } else {
      el['on' + ev] = fn;
    }
  }

  var isVertical = config.vertical;

  elem.className = (elem.className + ' range-slider ' + (isVertical ? 'range-slider-vertical' : 'range-slider-horizontal')).replace(/^ +/, "");
  range.className = ('range-slider-track ' + config.rangeClass).replace(/ +$/, "");
  dragger.className = ('dragger ' + config.draggerClass).replace(/ +$/, "");

  addEventTo(range, "mousedown", function(e) {
    html.className = (html.className + ' no-select').replace(/^ +/, "");
    rangeWidth = range[!isVertical ? 'offsetWidth' : 'offsetHeight'];
    rangeOffset = range[!isVertical ? 'offsetLeft' : 'offsetTop'];
    draggerWidth = dragger[!isVertical ? 'offsetWidth' : 'offsetHeight'];
    down = true;
    updateDragger(e);
    return false;
  });

  addEventTo(document, "mousemove", function(e) {
    updateDragger(e);
  });

  addEventTo(document, "mouseup", function(e) {
    html.className = html.className.replace(/(^| )no-select( |$)/g, "");
    down = false;
  });

  addEventTo(window, "resize", function(e) {
    var woh = dragger[!isVertical ? 'offsetWidth' : 'offsetHeight'];
    dragger.style[!isVertical ? 'left' : 'top'] = (((cachePosition / 100) * range[!isVertical ? 'offsetWidth' : 'offsetHeight']) - (woh / 2)) + 'px';
    down = false;
  });

  function updateDragger(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var pos = !isVertical ? e.pageX : e.pageY;
    if (!pos) {
      pos = !isVertical ? e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft : e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    if (down && pos >= rangeOffset && pos <= (rangeOffset + rangeWidth)) {
      dragger.style[!isVertical ? 'left' : 'top'] = (pos - rangeOffset - (draggerWidth / 2)) + 'px';
      cachePosition = Math.round(((pos - rangeOffset) / rangeWidth) * 100);
      config.drag(cachePosition);
    }
  }

  function initDragger() {
    var woh = dragger[!isVertical ? 'offsetWidth' : 'offsetHeight'];
    cachePosition = ((config.value / 100) * range[!isVertical ? 'offsetWidth' : 'offsetHeight']);
    dragger.style[!isVertical ? 'left' : 'top'] = (cachePosition - (woh / 2)) + 'px';
    config.drag(config.value);
  }

  range.appendChild(dragger);
  elem.appendChild(range);

  initDragger();

}





rangeSlider(document.getElementById('range-slider-1'), {
  value: 30,
  drag: function(v) {
    document.getElementById('result-area').innerHTML = v + '%';
  }
});
```

```css
.range-slider {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 60px;
}
.range-slider-track {
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.range-slider-track:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
}
.range-slider-track .dragger {
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: inherit;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: inherit;
  /* opacity:.6; */
}
.range-slider-vertical {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
.range-slider-vertical .range-slider-track {
  cursor: n-resize;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
}
.range-slider-vertical .range-slider-track:before {
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  left: 9px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
}
.range-slider-vertical .range-slider-track .dragger {
  width: inherit;
  height: 10px;
}
.no-select {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="range-slider-1"></div>
<p id="result-area"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to get the position of your container element `#range-slider-1`, that is the element which is being passed to the `rangeSlider` function at the bottom. If you got that you can subtract the position offset from the `pos` variable in the `updateDragger` function.

I have added `getElemPos` to get the elements position.
Now you can change `position` `left` to what ever you want.

Here is an example, this will only work for the horizontal slider not for the vertical one, but I'm sure you can now easily figure that out by yourself. ;)

```js
// This will help to get an elements position.
function getElemPos (elem) {
  var xPos = 0,
      yPos = 0;

  while (elem) {
    xPos += (elem.offsetLeft - elem.scrollLeft + elem.clientLeft);
    yPos += (elem.offsetTop - elem.scrollTop + elem.clientTop);
    elem = elem.offsetParent;
  }

  return { x: xPos, y: yPos };
}

function rangeSlider(elem, config) {

  var html = document.documentElement,
      range = document.createElement('div'),
      dragger = document.createElement('span'),
      down = false,
      rangeWidth, rangeOffset, draggerWidth, cachePosition;

  var defaults = {
    value: 0, // set default value on initiation from `0` to `100` (percentage based)
    vertical: false, // vertical or horizontal?
    rangeClass: "", // add extra custom class for the range slider track
    draggerClass: "", // add extra custom class for the range slider dragger
    drag: function(v) { /* console.log(v); */ } // function to return the range slider value into something
  };

  for (var i in defaults) {
    if (typeof config[i] == "undefined") config[i] = defaults[i];
  }

  function addEventTo(el, ev, fn) {
    if (el.addEventListener) {
      el.addEventListener(ev, fn, false);
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {
      el.attachEvent('on' + ev, fn);
    } else {
      el['on' + ev] = fn;
    }
  }

  var isVertical = config.vertical;

  elem.className = (elem.className + ' range-slider ' + (isVertical ? 'range-slider-vertical' : 'range-slider-horizontal')).replace(/^ +/, "");
  range.className = ('range-slider-track ' + config.rangeClass).replace(/ +$/, "");
  dragger.className = ('dragger ' + config.draggerClass).replace(/ +$/, "");

  addEventTo(range, "mousedown", function(e) {
    html.className = (html.className + ' no-select').replace(/^ +/, "");
    rangeWidth = range[!isVertical ? 'offsetWidth' : 'offsetHeight'];
    rangeOffset = range[!isVertical ? 'offsetLeft' : 'offsetTop'];
    draggerWidth = dragger[!isVertical ? 'offsetWidth' : 'offsetHeight'];
    down = true;
    updateDragger(e);
    return false;
  });

  addEventTo(document, "mousemove", function(e) {
    updateDragger(e);
  });

  addEventTo(document, "mouseup", function(e) {
    html.className = html.className.replace(/(^| )no-select( |$)/g, "");
    down = false;
  });

  addEventTo(window, "resize", function(e) {
    var woh = dragger[!isVertical ? 'offsetWidth' : 'offsetHeight'];
    dragger.style[!isVertical ? 'left' : 'top'] = (((cachePosition / 100) * range[!isVertical ? 'offsetWidth' : 'offsetHeight']) - (woh / 2)) + 'px';
    down = false;
  });

  var elemXY = getElemPos(elem);

  function updateDragger(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var pos = !isVertical ? e.pageX : e.pageY;

    if (!pos) {
      pos = !isVertical ? (e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft) : e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

    // Here you can substract the #range-slider-1 x postion from the mouse position.
    pos -= elemXY.x;

    if (down && pos >= rangeOffset && pos <= (rangeOffset + rangeWidth)) {
      dragger.style[!isVertical ? 'left' : 'top'] = (pos - rangeOffset - (draggerWidth / 2)) + 'px';
      cachePosition = Math.round(((pos - rangeOffset) / rangeWidth) * 100);
      config.drag(cachePosition);
    }
  }

  function initDragger() {
    var woh = dragger[!isVertical ? 'offsetWidth' : 'offsetHeight'];
    cachePosition = ((config.value / 100) * range[!isVertical ? 'offsetWidth' : 'offsetHeight']);
    dragger.style[!isVertical ? 'left' : 'top'] = (cachePosition - (woh / 2)) + 'px';
    config.drag(config.value);
  }

  range.appendChild(dragger);
  elem.appendChild(range);

  initDragger();

}

rangeSlider(document.getElementById('range-slider-1'), {
  value: 30,
  drag: function(v) {
    document.getElementById('result-area').innerHTML = v + '%';
  }
});
```

```css
.range-slider {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 25%;
}

.range-slider-track {
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.range-slider-track:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
}

.range-slider-track .dragger {
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: inherit;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: inherit;
  /* opacity:.6; */
}

.range-slider-vertical {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}

.range-slider-vertical .range-slider-track {
  cursor: n-resize;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
}

.range-slider-vertical .range-slider-track:before {
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  left: 9px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
}

.range-slider-vertical .range-slider-track .dragger {
  width: inherit;
  height: 10px;
}

.no-select {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="range-slider-1"></div>
<p id="result-area"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why do we need a while loop? Isn't an if statement enough?

Comment: You need a while loop to make sure to include all the parent elements. offsetTop and offsetLeft are relative to its padding edge. So what if your slider is nested inside some other elements that are positioned as well or have some margin. Hope that make sense.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your css code.

The `left` property/value is throwing off the `dragger` element. **[See here](https://jsfiddle.net/hh87u5so/1/)**. Once that is removed, the dragger functions as intended.

Perhaps it is a bug, I would [report it to the repo](https://github.com/tovic/simple-custom-range-slider/issues) (seems like you already have) and avoid using `position: absolute` and `left` or `right` properties until resolved.